# Calculate path to node in a tree

Tags: sql-server

The following is part of a bigger system. The tree data table and temporary table cannot be changed easily so I need to work with those. The tree structure is more complex (deeper and wider) but the following are illustrative of the problem I am trying to solve.

I have a simple tree structure:

```
AAA     
  - aaa 
      - 111
      - 222
```

that is represented in data as:

```
Id  ParentId  Text
------------------ 
1   NULL      AAA       
2   1         aaa   
3   2         111
4   2         222
```

for a common function there is a temporary table where I want to determine which records need to be used to ultimately build the path to a particular item:

```
Id  ParentId  Text  UseRecord
----------------------------- 
1   NULL      AAA   False   
2   1         aaa   False       
3   2         111   False   
4   2         222   False
```

So for instance if I wanted to find which records are necessary to build the tree to item "222" after updating the temporary table it would look like:

```
Id  ParentId  Text  UseRecord
----------------------------- 
1   NULL      AAA   True    
2   1         aaa   True        
3   2         111   False   
4   2         222   True
```

What is the SQL statement I need to achieve the above result assuming it updates UseRecord and its only input is the Id value of 4 (ie "222"'s record).

This has to be really simple and fast, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out. All pointers appreciated.

Comment: How is this supposed to work when you later want to reuse the table to mark rows for another path? Does the query you are looking for need to both set the required rows to True *and* reset those unnecessary to False or are you expecting to reset all the rows to False every time separately, prior to running the [not yet worked out] query?

Comment: @AndriyM We will keep setting additional rows to TRUE for each path (rows are not reset to false between calls). What we will be left with is all the rows needed to satisfy all the paths needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to fetch `Id` at parent' levels:

```
DECLARE @Id int = 4;

WITH cte(level, Id, ParentId) AS(
    SELECT 0, Id, ParentId FROM @data WHERE id = @Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.level+1, d.Id, d.ParentId FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN @data d ON c.ParentId = d.Id
)
SELECT Id, Level FROM cte
;
```

#### Output

With `@Id = 4`, This query returns the path with several Ids:

```
Id  Level
4   0
2   1
1   2
```

It only returns Ids on the path from the root up to the Id store in `@Id`. This is probably all is needed. I didn't try to update the `@data` table.

However this can easily be done by replacing the `SELECT` by an `UPDATE`:

```
WITH ...
...
UPDATE @data SET [UseRecord] = 1
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM cte)
;

SELECT * FROM @data;
```

#### Notes

It is uneasy to say whether it will be efficient and fast. There are not enough information and details in the question (data model, number of rows, quantity of data, indexes, etc.).

It is worth mentioning that it is probably a bad idea to update the temp table and it may also be a bad idea to use a temp table in the first place.

Perhaps the same result can be achieved with a single query (SELECT with cte) without creating a temp table. It could avoid tons of IO (read and write the temp table X times). The above query is a starting point anyhow.

#### Data used

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(Id int, ParentId int, [text] varchar(5));
INSERT INTO @data(Id, ParentId, [text]) VALUES
    (1, NULL, 'AAA')
    , (2, 1, 'aaa') 
    , (3, 2, '111')
    , (4, 2, '222');
```

Replace @data by your temp table name in the query.

Comment: Thanks for that. As I said I am constrained by the fact that I need to manipulate the temp table specified due to other aspects of the system (its a legacy system). Ultimately we need to get a bunch of paths based on a number of leaf nodes. The end result will be the simple SELECT over the temporary table where UseRecord is TRUE. Supremely efficient - no, but this is not a blue sky solution I can implement. So what I need to do is to make sure that the updates in to the temp table are fast so that I don't add anymore overhead than necessary.

Comment: Ok, I have added the update to the query. I am giving you pointers but information such as: How big are those temp tables? (rows) Can you alter them? (indexes) would be useful.

Comment: I was able to use the CTE as the basis for what I needed to do and so far so good.